# Reactive way of implementing 'standard pagination'

Tags: project-reactor

I am just starting with Spring Reactor and want to implement something that I would call 'standard pagination', don't know if there is technical term for this. Basically no matter what start and end date is passed to method, I want to return same amound of data, evenly distributed. 
This will be used for some chart drawing in the future.

I figured out rough copy with algorithm that does exactly that, unfortunatelly before I can filter results I need to either count() or take last index() and block to get this number.

This block is surelly not the reactive way to do this, also it makes flux to call DB twice for data (or am I missing something?)

Is there any operator than can help me and get result from count() somehow down the stream for further usage, it would need to compute anyway before stream can be processed, but to get rid of calling DB two times?

I am using mongoDB reactive driver.

```
        Flux<StandardEntity> results = Flux.from(
                mongoCollectionManager.getCollection(channel)
                .find( and(gte("lastUpdated", begin), lte("lastUpdated", end))))
                .map(d -> new StandardEntity(d.getString("price"), d.getString("lastUpdated")));

        Long lastIndex = results
                .count()
                .block();

        final double standardPage = 10.0D;
        final double step = lastIndex / standardPage;
        final double[] counter = {0.0D};

        return
                results
                        .take(1)
                        .mergeWith(
                                results
                                        .skip(1)
                                        .filter(e -> {
                                            if (lastIndex > standardPage)
                                                if (counter[0] >= step) {
                                                    counter[0] = counter[0] - step + 1;
                                                    return true;
                                                } else {
                                                    counter[0] = counter[0] + 1;
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            else
                                                return true;
                                        }));
```

Comment: As far as I am checking in debugger it actually calls find() only once, so I guess this solution is acceptable. I thought block() will trigger flux once, and then WebFlux will trigger it second time.

Comment: Found another approach, after calling count() I use doOnSuccess to calculate step, and setting lastIndex to count's return value, then I use operator thenMany and paste all code below 'return'. This way I can return one chain without splitting them and calling block()